# append content with attributes to newly created content in jquery

Tags: jquery

Objective:

```
   <div id="g_1" class="grp">
   <span id="g_i_1" class="grp_icon"></span>
   <span id="g_mng_1" class="grp_name"></span> 
   <span id="g_des_1" class="grp_des"></span> 
   <span id="g_lock_1" class="grp_lock"></span> 
   <span id="g_vis_1" class="grp_vis"></span> 
   </div>
```

jquery code:

```
 $('<div/>', {id: 'g_'+ e.GID, class: 'grp'})
    .append($('<span/>'), {id: 'g_i_'+ e.GID, class: 'grp_icon'})
    .append($('<span/>'), {id: 'g_mng_'+ e.GID, class: 'grp_name'})
    .append($('<span/>'), {id: 'g_des_'+ e.GID, class: 'grp_des'})
    .append($('<span/>'), {id: 'g_lock_'+ e.GID, class: 'grp_lock'})
    .append($('<span/>'), {id: 'g_vis_'+ e.GID, class: 'grp_vis'})
```

result:

```
   <div id="g_1" class="grp"> 
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   </div>
```

Why are the id and class attributes being created for the parent element, but not for the child elements, however the child elements are being created??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object with the attributes should be in the arguments to `$()` that create that element. `.append()` doesn't take an attributes argument, it just takes the elements to append.

```js
var e = {GID: 1};
var div = $('<div/>', {id: 'g_'+ e.GID, "class": 'grp'})
    .append($('<span/>', {id: 'g_i_'+ e.GID, "class": 'grp_icon'}))
    .append($('<span/>', {id: 'g_mng_'+ e.GID, "class": 'grp_name'}))
    .append($('<span/>', {id: 'g_des_'+ e.GID, "class": 'grp_des'}))
    .append($('<span/>', {id: 'g_lock_'+ e.GID, "class": 'grp_lock'}))
    .append($('<span/>', {id: 'g_vis_'+ e.GID, "class": 'grp_vis'}));
console.log(div[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you should quote `class` when using it as a property name. `class` is a Javascript keyword, and some browsers will report a syntax error if you don't quote it.

Comment: But I want to define the children's attributes... Thanks for the advice regarding 'class'.

Comment: That's what this does. `$("<span/>", { ... })` defines the attributes of the span.

Comment: It's just like the way you defined the attributes of the `DIV`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't notice the closing parenthesis after the span element